# Multiple instances of user control on same webform and storing to viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

- .NET 4.51 WebForms

I have a user control that I want to store some custom information into ViewState[]. Now while I can generate a static GUID and use that as the key, if I have a second user control then I will have a clash. So how do I generate a predictable unique key for the particular instance of the user control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the clientID of the user control instance. And perhaps append it to the unique ID.

Comment: I have seen vague references that a control gets its own instance of viewstate to prevent colisions. Can anyone verify that?

Comment: I haven't come across. In fact you need the ID predictable.